# How to enforce settings on debian Vim?

Tags: vimrc, options

I have some settings in my debian (in `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`), which are overwritten by some plugins. Exactly which ones, at the moment is it hard to say, however I find it quite an annoying one.

I found the problem after some of my settings (in `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`) simply did not work. I have made a debugging with the command `vim -V9logfile.log testfile` and I have found this:

```
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/debian.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/colors/lists/default.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syncolor.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/synload.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/filetype.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/autoload/dist/script.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/scripts.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syntax.vim
finished sourcing /etc/vim/vimrc.local
finished sourcing /etc/vim/vimrc
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/filetype.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/ftplugin.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/indent.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/nosyntax.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syncolor.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/synload.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syntax.vim
finished sourcing $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/gzip.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/logiPat.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/manpager.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/matchparen.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/rrhelper.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/spellfile.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/tohtml.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/scripts.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/ftplugin/vim.vim
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim90/indent/vim.vim
```

Fine. So, I have a lot of sources read in before and also after my `vimrc.local`, which is the ordinary place in debian for system-wide vi settings. Somewhere there, my settings are overwritten and it really annoys me. I believe, what I set up manually, should be stronger settings as some distro defaults.

Maybe we have a "battle of worlds" here, i.e. debian has some ideas how configs should look and vim has contradicting ones? Or it might be only some bug? Anyways, what should I do to let these things do what I want?

P.S.: The settings are:

```
set mouse=
set ttymouse=
```

But please do not make this the focus of the answer. I do not find first this problem, and mysteriously unworking config directives are the worst what a command line guy can annoy. Question is to get a clear picture, what is the root of the cause in the general case and how to solve it. If debian is maybe too orthodox then I will find a way to enforce into what I want from him.)

Comment: Couple tips: use `:verbose set opt?` and `:verbose setlocal opt?` to find out where opt was last set. And, unless you need system-wide configuration, try a user vimrc (_e.g._, `~/.vim/vimrc`). Unfortunately overly general questions are hard to answer, so I think it would be better to focus in on what you want to solve.

Comment: OMG, it is set up in `/usr/share/vim/vim90/defaults.vim`! Which is after my vimrc.local... the problem was very simple, `set mouse=` worked well directly but not in my `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`. I... just felt that something overwrites it. And now I know, who!!

Comment: But I do not know, how to make this question useful. I think it is likely useful, I had the some problem already not once, but only now I had the... mental resource to track it. I think so is this question not so bad and it could help a lot for the googlers of the future. Previously I did not find anything by google, this is why am I here.

Comment: `:verbose set opt?` is the solution, if you make an answer from it I will happily accept.

Comment: Another victim of `defaults.vim`… and of not doing *their* config where it belongs: in *their* `$HOME`.

Comment: @romainl Problem is that files under /usr/share are overwritten with possible package upgrades in the future. This is why user-defined configuration (in /etc) should get into effect *after* the /usr/share settings, and this is the normal debian way, except now.

Comment: `$HOME` is where you should do that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Copying my comment here:

Couple tips: use `:verbose set opt?` and `:verbose setlocal opt?` to find out where `opt` was last set. And, unless you need system-wide configuration, try a user vimrc (*e.g.*, `~/.vim/vimrc`): etc and friends for system-wide configuration are rarely touched by most unless you are a sysadmin who really needs to tweak something for all users to make Vim work.

It seems that the `defaults.vim` script which is in effect if you have no vimrc (or if you explicitly execute with `:runtime`) is changing options after your etc scripts. Creating an (empty) user vimrc will disable it, though you may miss other such « defaults ». Copy the bits that you understand and like to said vimrc.